# Pointer to a map

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go

Having some maps defined as:

```
var valueToSomeType = map[uint8]someType{...}
var nameToSomeType = map[string]someType{...}
```

I would want a variable that points to the address of the maps (to don't copy all variable). I tried it using:

```
valueTo := &valueToSomeType
nameTo := &nameToSomeType
```

but at using `valueTo[number]`, it shows
*internal compiler error: var without type, init: new*

How to get it?

**Edit**

The error was showed by another problem.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Maps are reference types, so they are always passed by reference. You don't need a pointer. [Go Doc](https://blog.golang.org/maps)

Comment: Take a look here: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/29/there-is-no-pass-by-reference-in-go

Comment: Yes, Dave described it better. Read his blog entry.

Comment: It's interesting that on the one hand you can say a map is always a reference. Meaning a map value is a pointer. so when you use the variable of the map, you're utilizing this pointer to set something in the map. 

And on the other hand a map is not a reference. Because the map value is a pointer, and the pointer value is copied around and the dereferencing happens automatically.

Answer (score 54):

More specifically, from the [Golang Specs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels):

> Slices, **maps** and channels are **reference types** that do not require the extra indirection of an allocation with `new`.
>   The built-in function make takes a type `T`, which must be a slice, map or channel type, optionally followed by a type-specific list of expressions.
>   It returns a value of type `T` (*not `*T`*).
>   The memory is initialized as described in the section on initial values

However, regarding [function calls](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls), the parameters are passed **by value** (always).
Except the value of a map parameter is a pointer.

Comment: @JuliusF both, but I am more precise in my answer: the pointer is passed by value. More on the "pass by value" at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23046811/6309.

Comment: @VonC thank you so much for this. I will repeat this is my head now ten times every night before going to sleep "the pointer is passed by value".

Comment: @XamEseerts Great! Next step in your pre-nocturnal habits: https://arpitbhayani.me/techie/how-sleepsort-helped-me-understand-concurrency-in-golang.html

Answer (score 9):

@Mue 's answer is correct.

Following simple program is enough to validate:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string, 10)
    add(m)
    fmt.Println(m["tom"]) // expect nil ???
}

func add(m map[string]string) {
    m["tom"] = "voldemort"
}
```

The output of this program is

```
voldemort
```

Tf the map was passed by value, then addition to the map in the function add() would not have any effect in the main method. But we see the value added by the method add(). This verifies that the map's pointer is passed to the add() method.

Comment: the map's pointer is passed by value. m["tom"] knows how to dereference whatever pointer `m` actually is. in Go, when you say "the map" it actually means the pointer to the map. Because go syntax abstracted needing to write `*m` away.

Comment: BTW, it would never be nil, it could be an empty string instead (if pointer magic was not working).